# How do I count the number of occurances of a specific sequence of numbers within a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

This is going to be a bit strange,  I have a column of 750 rows populated with whole numbers ranging from 1-10.  I am trying to look at that data as a **series of 3 row sequences**, and *count* the number of occurrences for each sequence as it's shown in the following  screen shot :

[Trying to find and count 3 cell sequences in excel.  Column A is the observation column, with integer values from 1-3.  Column I is a listing of all observed 3-value sequences, and column J is the number of occurrences each of those sequences are observed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRr2Z.jpg)

Column A is the observation column, with integer values from 1-3 for this example.  Column I is a listing of all observed 3-value sequences, and column J is the number of occurrences each of those sequences are observed.  Column I is displayed as a text value, but it would be better to have that one column turned into 3 separate columns; one for each value in the sequence.

I am attempting this as a step to create the observation matrix of a 2nd order Markov chain.  In a previous version, I only needed a first order matrix, which was composed of 2 value sequences.  I accomplished this by creating 100 columns; one for every possible combination.  Then in every row of each of those columns, I had the cell look at the observed value (column A) for that row, and the row above it, and if the sequence matched the sequence for that column, it would output a 1.  In the end I summed each column, and used that info to generate the counts for the observation matrix.

I tried to write this out as a massive grid of all possible combinations using in cell functions, but it quickly became obvious that this approach would not work; 1000 columns of 750 rows poses a computational problem.  It strikes me that there might be a simple way to do this is vba, but I am not sure if it is even possible.  I have started teaching myself, but there is still a lot I do not know.  Is it even possible, or am I wasting my time?

There are two outputs I need: I need the list of all observed sequences.  The integers may be from 1-10, but not all 10, or all combination of 10 may be present.  I do not need the combinations which do not occur.  I also need to know the number of times each sequence is observed.

I am running this on a Windows 7 PC using Microsoft Excel 1010.  I am using Microsoft Excel because it is the only math program I have, and it is the one I am most comfortable with.

Comment: +1 for showing the image.  -1 for not showing what you've tried. I'm not sure I understand  column E. Why does Column E start with `1-7-8` and not with `8-3-4`?

Comment: Why are you doing this in Excel at all?

Comment: Do you need help determining the three-number sequences, getting the list of unique three-number sequences, or just doing the count?

Comment: @DavidOliver sorry I had a typo in my previous comment. Here's what I meant: Do you want this for EVERY combination or just whichever combinations are in column E? What is the final output? You need to be a little more clear with your entire problem. Simplify*ing* your example to make the question easier to understand actually obfuscates what you're trying to achieve and hides away incorrect assumptions you may have.

Comment: I have edited the entire question for clarity, and hopefully simplified it.  I replaced the graphic with a new one to represent the simplified version.  Please let me know if there is still anything unclear

Comment: @DavidOliver Are helper columns allowed or not? Because that would make the answer less difficult.

Comment: @AndreTerra there's always someone who says this for pretty much any prolem.  This seems like a perfectly good thing to use excel for to me!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Excel. For a start, try [this online ngram analyzer tool](http://guidetodatamining.com/ngramAnalyzer/).

On the text field, try putting in `8 3 4 3 1 7 8 3 8 3 8`.
Choose `Using Frequency`, and show `trigrams` that occur at least `one` times.

Submit it, then you get a list of trigrams along with their frequencies. Just ignore the lines with one or two numbers only.

---

If you need this behaviour dynamically and programmatically, I could help you make a script that does exactly this calculation based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't help but find a solution for this. I used R instead, because it just makes sense. The code is below, and also available on this [R-Fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=Wv6BvZyQ&version=23)

Please notice that the code below has a section for generating mock data. In practice, you'll actually have to replace that with your actual data which would be stored in a vector called `x` as explained in the code.

If you don't care about the observations that don't occur, then the code is very very simple:

```
x <- c("01", "02", "03", "01", "02", "03", "01", "02 ", "03") # your Column A
n <- 3 # number of elements in each combination. configurable.

# create a vector with n-sized sequences of characters. (e.g. n = 3 -> "XX-YY-ZZ")
mydata <- x
for (i in 2:n) {
    y <- c(x[-i], x[i])
    mydata <- paste(mydata, y, sep="-")
}

# calculate the frequency of each observation and save into data table
frequencies <- data.frame(table(mydata))
head(frequencies)
```

The output then will be something like:

```
    mydata Freq
1 01-02-02    2
2 01-04-04    2
3 01-05-05    1
4 01-07-07    1
5 01-10-10    1
6 02-02-02    1
```

If you do care about showing all possibilities, the code is a bit messier:

```
n <- 3 # number of elements in each combination. configurable.

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#            THIS PART SIMPLY GENERATES MOCK DATA. REPLACE WITH ACTUAL DATA          #
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
universe <- 1:10 # your range of numbers
m <- 100 # number of rows in the mock data

# generate some mock data with a simple m-sized vector of numbers within 'universe'
set.seed(1337) # hardcode random seed so mock data can be reproduced
x <- sample(universe, m, replace=TRUE)
x <- formatC(x, width=nchar(max(universe)), flag=0) # pad our data with 0s as needed
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                               END OF MOCK DATA PART                                #
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# At this point, you should have a variable x which contains a sequence of
# numbers stored as characters (text) e.g. "01" "04" "10" "04" "06"

# create a vector with n-sized sequences of characters. (e.g. n = 3 -> "XX-YY-ZZ")
mydata <- x
for (i in 2:n) {
    y <- c(x[-i], x[i])
    mydata <- paste(mydata, y, sep="-")
}

# calculate the frequency of each observation and save into data table
frequencies <- data.frame(table(mydata))

# generate all possible permutations and save them to a data table called
p <- as.matrix(expand.grid(replicate(n, universe, simplify=FALSE)))
p <- formatC(p, width=nchar(max(universe)), flag=0)
q <- apply(p, 1, paste, collapse="-")
permutations <- data.frame(q, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # broken into separate   step for nicer variable name in df
permutations$Freq <- 0 # fill with zeroes 
permutations$Freq[match(frequencies$mydata, permutations$q)] <- frequencies$Freq

head(permutations)
```

The output will be something like:

```
         q Freq
1 01-01-01    0
2 02-01-01    0
3 03-01-01    2
4 04-01-01    0
5 05-01-01    1
6 06-01-01    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper column that concatenates the data in groups of 3, and then a) use countif to count the sequences. or b) use a pivot table.

In cell B2 put `=CONCATENATE(A2,",",A3,",",A4)` and drag down (double click the bottom right corner)

### countif method

then, putting `=COUNTIF(B:B,I2)` in J2, you get the totals, as below.

[image: countif]

if you don't like the 0s then just autofilter.  Although I imagine you'll be using a larger dataset than this and probably won't have any.

[image]

### pivottable

A more advanced and imho a more elegant solution would be to use a pivottable.  Using the same formula in column B.

Insert a pivottable based on the table in cols A and B. With "ROW LABELS" as Column B and values as COUNT (not sum) of column B.

[image]

[image]

You don't have to type out the sequences to be counted, excel just finds everything in column B automatically.

Also, it's a generalised solution for any length of sequences, and any number of digits used (just add more cells to your concatenation in column B).  Also, for example, looking for 5 digit sequences in the data:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
4
3
2
1
```

repeated for 100 rows gives:

[image]

Piece of cake.